# Socket.io auto disconnect in Android

Tags: android, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm using socket.io in Android.I successfully connected my android application in node.js server.Everything is perfect ,but i try to create connection on Sturtup ,but socket automatically disconnected
This is my source

```
public class AutoRunService extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static Socket socket;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
        Toast.makeText(UApplication.getInstance(), "Application is ready to  open ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        seSocketConnection(context);

    }
}


public void seSocketConnection(final Context context) {
    try {

        socket = IO.socket("http://192.168.101.139:8080");
        socket.on("onconnect", new Emitter.Listener() {

                    @Override
                    public void call(Object... args) {
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                        Log.e("AutoRunService", "onconnect");

                        try {
                            obj.put("host", "************");
                            obj.put("entity", new DeviceManager(UApplication.getInstance()).getDeviceId());
                            socket.emit("initialize", obj);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
        ).on("onerror", new Emitter.Listener() {

                    @Override
                    public void call(Object... args) {
                        Log.e("AutoRunService", "onerror");


                    }
                }
        ).on("device", new Emitter.Listener() {

                    @Override
                    public void call(Object... args) {
                        Log.e("AutoRunService", "device");

                        Intent i = new Intent(context, WelcomeImageActivity.class);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        context.startActivity(i);


                    }
                }
        ).on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, new Emitter.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                Log.e("AutoRunService", "EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR");
            }


        }).on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
              //  socket.disconnect();
                Log.e("AutoRunService", "EVENT_DISCONNECT");

            }

        });
        socket.connect();

    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("AutoRunService", e.toString());

    }
}
```

}

Manifest source code

```
 <receiver
        android:name=".AutoRunService"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

o course,i have internet connection permission in manifest.I don't know what is a wrong in my source.As i said socket connection working perfect in Activity
How i can solve my problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Only thing worked me is to downgrade the `socket` version in `gradle`

**Using this and worked**

```
 implementation('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3') {
        // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to do this 
opts.forceNew = true;
opts.reconnection = true;

Just do that :
socket = IO.socket("http://192.168.101.139:8080");

Let me know if it works.Hope it helps you:)

Also make socket static.

Comment: Why ? Can you tell me ? @M.Saad Lakhan

Comment: there is no documentation for these features I had the issue I did this and issue is resolved. Try this it will resolve your issue.Hope so :)

Comment: Make socket static also

Comment: Creates a new Manager for the given URL, and attempts to reuse an existing Manager for subsequent calls, unless the multiplex option is passed with false. Passing this option is the equivalent of passing 'force new connection': true or forceNew: true.

A new Socket instance is returned for the namespace specified by the pathname in the URL, defaulting to /. For example, if the url is http://localhost/users, a transport connection will be established to http://localhost and a Socket.IO connection will be established to /users.
Reference:
https://socket.io/docs/client-api/

Comment: I updated my source,but still not working @M.Saad Lakhan

Comment: Do you have an application level class in your project ? if yes then create static socket over there and call it wherever you want.

Comment: I have BaseActivity Class da and i exteded it in my two activities  @ M.Saad Lakhan

Comment: Create static socket in your base class and connect it whereever you need and then emit what you want to after that remember to disconnect the socket when finished your operation and again connect when you need it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138642/discussion-between-baggio-and-m-saad-lakhan).

Comment: I created it and as i said my baseActivity's socket connection working perfect in both Activity.But i want to get Connection in startup(inboot service) without open application.did you unsertand me ? @ M.Saad Lakhan

Comment: Yes I get it what is your requirement you have to introduce application level class.
Uses of Application Class:

access to variables across the Application,
you can use the Application to start certain things like analytics etc. since the application class is started before Activitys or Servicess are being run,
there is a overridden method called onConfiguration() changed that is triggered when the application configuration is changed (horizontal to vertical & vice-versa),
there is also a event called onLowMemory() that is triggered when the Android device is low on memory.

Comment: can you continue discussion in chat ? @ M.Saad Lakhan

Comment: Buddy just study application level class it will solve your issues create socket there before loading any of your activity then it will keep on running on back end

Comment: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Understanding-the-Android-Application-Class
This link is very useful please study and follow this it will lead you to what you want mate :) Hope it helps :)

Comment: Ok.As you said ,I must create socket connection inside application class.(done) I also overrided onConfiguration in Application class.my question is that does my socket connection method would start in autoRun ?or not,how i can do this @ M.Saad Lakhan

Comment: if you create your socket in application class and please make it static. then yes ur socket is created now in your base activity call this socket and connect it do whatever is required.It will work mate :)

Comment: Ok .i inserted my seSocketConnection method inside Application class's  onCreate method @ M.Saad Lakhan

Comment: This is the way it will surely work just relax and work on it this is the right way.It will solve your issue. Don't panic ... just relax budy! Best of luck :)

Comment: Maybe something wrong,because connection status has changed after restarted device.I mean command line node.js .First time is connected status and then from example 5 sec later,status is disconnected @ M.Saad Lakhan

Comment: any solution?  @M.Saad Lakhan

Answer (score 0):

```
 socket.on("onconnect", new Emitter.Listener() {

                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                    Log.e("AutoRunService", "onconnect");

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

                    try {
                        obj.put("host", "************");
                        obj.put("entity", new DeviceManager(UApplication.getInstance()).getDeviceId());
                        socket.emit("initialize", obj);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
    )enter code here
```

Comment: Please add an explanations of how this code answers the question. Please read the SO guidelines before posting.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. The easy fix for this is just emit a random event in my case 'alive' and (see code) . I was using Background service in order to keep socket connection alive forever ( using foreground off course). In My background Service:-

```
handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("keeping socket alive");
            socket.emit("alive", from);
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
        }
    };
```

I emit alive event after every second and then on server side:-

```
socket.on('alive', (from)=>{
    io.to(from).emit('alive');
})
```

Make sure that you are not altering the ping timeout and ping interval things

```
const app = express()
let http = require('http').Server(app)
let io = require('socket.io')(http);
```